# How to Create mobile and Desktop menu same Magento 1.9?

Tags: magento-1.9, menu

> I am installing One Theme of Magento 1.9 and in this theme have mobile
>   and the desktop menu was Different. Please anyone Can Help me how I
>   can do the same.

**Website: http://nn.packparadise.com**

> Thank you in Advance